# Stuck with input/output shapes in keras, lstm

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I'm trying train a time series of energy demand using lstm. I had used timestamp and got the results but for this experiment I'm trying to split date time in days, month, year, hours. So after splitting data my csv file looks like this

```
timestamp     | day | month | year | hour | demand
01-07-15 1:00 |  1  |   7   | 2015 |   1  | 431607
```

I'm using keras for LSTM(I'm very new to it). I have following code written so far.

```
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

dataframe = read_csv('patched_data_sorted.csv', engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
trainX = dataset[:, 1:5]
sampleSize = len(trainX)
trainX = trainX.reshape(1, len(trainX), 4)
trainY = dataset[:, 5]
trainY = trainY.reshape(1, len(trainY))
print(trainY)

# print(trainX)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(sampleSize, 4)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
print(trainPredict)
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1, 20544)
```

I'm not sure why is this happening but I think I'm not reshaping correctly.

Comment: Why does the trainX have 3 dimensions. And why are you reshaping trainY as `.reshape(1, len(trainY))`?

Comment: because lstm requires 3d array of shape(Samples, Time Steps, Features). and for the output shape should have same no of samples

Comment: In that case, why are you keeping 1 in place of samples and `sampleSize` in plce of time steps in your code

Comment: I was following this post https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

Answer (score 1):

In your data you have a label for every timestep of the sequence. Your current network is set up to have only one label for the whole sequence.

To get an output for every timestep you need to add `return_sequences=True` to your LSTM and wrap the `Dense` layer in a `TimeDistributed` layer so that it gets applied in every timestep.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(sampleSize, 4), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```